# How to completely reset drive permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions, administrator

I've made the fatal and stupid mistake of messing around with permissions. Specifically, I added a deny Write rule for administrators to my C: drive. In my efforts to revert this change I have attempted to change the owner of the drive from TrustedInstaller to myself and then removing the deny rule, however many folders remain unchanged and prompt an Access Denied window when changing the permissions. Obviously, soon after a restart most apps stopped working and could not open.

Next, I backed up whatever I could and tried resetting my PC. I chose the Keep My Files option when resetting my PC and let it do it's thing. Now the apps I re-install are able to work, but the folders that denied access earlier are still the same. I'm unable to do anything to these folders (C:\Users\...\Downloads, C:\Windows, C:\Program Files, etc.) other than see the contents.

I am willing to nuke it all and go back to factory settings if that is what it takes. How should I completely reset the permissions to default? Will a complete delete-everything PC reset change it back?

I'm using Windows 10. Unfortunately, I have no System Restore points set up.

Comment: An owner can always change permissions even if permissions say they can't. An administrator can take ownership of anything, even if permissions say they can't. These are known as privileges and are attached to users. Permissions are attached to objects.

Comment: I am unable to claim ownership to files and folders in Program Files, with a prompt saying Access is Denied. Claiming as Administrators itself also gives the same prompt.

Comment: Use [psexec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec). Start CMD from SYSTEM account in interactive mode and remove errorneous access permission.

Comment: I've tried running it from SYSTEM (`psexec -i -s cmd.exe`) and then from the new terminal ran `icacls C: /reset` but it still says access denied

Comment: `reset` doesn't do what you think it does. Tell us what you did? In a normal windows installation `reset` will do almost nothing. Type `icacls /?`.

Comment: Have you tried launching 'Explorer.exe' from the "RunasSystem" utility? http://reboot.pro/files/file/237-runassystem-and-runfromtoken/

Comment: Please have a look at the __Related__ articles on your posted page. Here is one which might help a lot. https://superuser.com/questions/952788/how-can-i-reset-permissions-in-system-folders-to-the-correct-settings?rq=1

Comment: @Mark From start till now: Added deny rule to Write for administrators for C drive itself, then claimed ownership as my own account on the C drive, then tried to remove deny rule from C drive. However, claiming ownership and removing the rule did not work for many of the files/folders in the drive. Which icacls command should I be running instead? Or what other program should I be running as SYSTEM?

Comment: @vssher There's no reason to run `explorer.exe` as `SYSTEM`, and AFAIK, would never be recommended.  `icacls` is the correct tool for the issue experienced.

Answer (score 0):

After backing up my important files, I took the nuclear option of resetting the PC and allowing it to delete everything in the C: Drive.